# How strong is Satoru Gojo from Jujutsu Kaisen?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

In *Jujutsu Kaisen*, I know that one of Satoru's primary techniques is the convergence of an infinite series due to which he can bring "Infinity" to reality. Things approaching him slow down and never reach. Also, by amplifying the "Limitless" (infinite) and "Negative Numbers", impossible situations like having 1 apples are born. By doing that, he can create a magnetic effect between two things, release immense power, and much more.

Can anyone beat this guy? How strong is he?

Comment: Hi, we'll assume that you're talking about his strength in-universe comparative to other characters in *Jujutsu Kaisen*, not with characters from different series or even real-world comparison, since the latter will be off-topic.